# iOS - Objective C - UITablview section disable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have three section in tableview. Three section cell contain 3 different view controllers. When user have chance to tap 2 different section in tableview we are getting crash due to back navigation crash. UINavigationController Exception. How do we disable the section to avoid more than once seclection.

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore the cell section you don't want to handle:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath.section == 1) // Don't do anything where row in section 1 is pressed
        return nil;
    else
    {
        //handle cell selection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //once you get control in this section disable the table for 1 second than in this duration your navigation controller will pop and user will not able to tap second time

    [self performSelector:@selector(enableTable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    tbl.userInteractionEnabled=NO; 

}

-(void)enableTable
{
   tbl.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a table view delegate method tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:

The OS will call that method before selecting a cell.

Implement that method, and if the section in the index path is the one you don't want to select, return nil.

If your section number is defined as K_SECTION_TO_IGNORE, your code might look like this:

```
#define K_SECTION_TO_IGNORE 1

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.section == K_SECTION_TO_IGNORE)
    return nil;
  else
    return indexPath;
}
```